# Is using Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor recommended in app widget

Tags: android, multithreading

Currently, in my main app, I am sending multiple texts to status bar object.

My status bar object, is going to display multiple texts sequentially, with sleep time of N seconds for each display interval.

Here's my implementation in my main app.

```
public synchronized void setNextText(final CharSequence text) {
    if (executor == null) {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fragment fragment = getTargetFragment();
            if (fragment instanceof OnStatusBarUpdaterListener) {
                ((OnStatusBarUpdaterListener)fragment).setNextText(text);


                try {
                    // Allow 1 seconds for every text.
                    Thread.sleep(Constants.STATUS_BAR_UPDATER_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now, I would like to have the same behavior in app widget. I was wondering, is using `Executor` being recommended in app widget environment? If not, what class I should use to achieve the similar objective?

I do have experience in using `HandlerThread` + `AlarmManager` in app widget. It works good so far. However, the operation done by the `runnable` is one time. It doesn't sleep and wait.

The following is the code which I use to update stock price in fixed interval.

```
// This code is trigger by AlarmManager periodically.
if (holder.updateStockPriceHandlerThread == null) {
    holder.updateStockPriceHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("updateStockPriceHandlerThread" + appWidgetId);
    holder.updateStockPriceHandlerThread.start();
    holder.updateStockPriceWorkerQueue = new Handler(holder.updateStockPriceHandlerThread.getLooper());
    holder.updateStockPriceWorkerQueue.post(getUpdateStockPriceRunnable(...
}
```

However, I have a feeling that, for use case "display multiple texts sequentially, with sleep time of N seconds for each display interval", `AlarmManager` might not be a good solution. Imagine I have 100 texts. Having to set 100 alarms for 100 texts doesn't sound good...

Comment: By "home widget", do you mean [app widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)?

Comment: Opps. I always communicate with my clients using term "home widget". I change it back to "app widget".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `AppWidgetProvider` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`. Once your callback (e.g., `onUpdate()`) returns, your process can be terminated at any point.

If that is not a problem — if you fail to finish the semi-animation that you are doing, that's OK — using an `Executor` from `onUpdate()` could work.

If you want to make sure that the text changes go to completion, delegate the app widget updating to a `Service`, where you use your `Executor`. Call `stopSelf()` on the `Service` when you are done, so it can go away and not artificially keep your process around.

Comment: Sorry. Do you mean that, if I perform `executor.execute` in `onUpdate`, there's chance that the submitted runnable can be terminated sometimes, due to the behavior of "Once your callback (e.g., onUpdate()) returns, your process can be terminated at any point."?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: Correct. I am hoping that the N in your question is low (a few seconds) and that the total number of pieces of text is also low (a few values, call this M). You need your process to be around for M * N seconds for your set up timed updates to complete. However, once `onUpdate()` returns, your process can go away at any point, possibly well before M * N seconds elapses.

Comment: Yes. N will be few seconds. M should be less than 5.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, some of my clients using Android O complain my home widget is not working (It works for them previously). (Although I'm not able to reproduce at my side) Do you think using Executor still valid in home widget case?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: Pure background stuff can run for at most a minute on Android 8.0+, and kicking off a background service from the background is blocked. You could try moving your logic to a `JobIntentService`, `sleep()`-ing between times that you need to update the app widget, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Well the singleThread instance work creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread. meaning only thread to process your operation. But in you case use at least two. Your operations sounds expensive.
To conclude your question stick with the executor service as it thread safe.